# How does sizeof(long long) <= sizeof(intptr_t) work under 32 bits?

Tags: c++

Now there is a piece of public code in chromium/v8 as follows:

https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/src/execution/simulator-base.h#62

```
  // Convert integral argument to intptr_t.
  template <typename T>
  static typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, intptr_t>::type
  ConvertArg(T arg) {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(intptr_t), "type bigger than ptrsize");
#if V8_TARGET_ARCH_MIPS64 || V8_TARGET_ARCH_LOONG64 || \
    V8_TARGET_ARCH_RISCV32 || V8_TARGET_ARCH_RISCV64
    // The MIPS64, LOONG64 and RISCV64 calling convention is to sign extend all
    // values, even unsigned ones.
    using signed_t = typename std::make_signed<T>::type;
    return static_cast<intptr_t>(static_cast<signed_t>(arg));
#else
    // Standard C++ convertion: Sign-extend signed values, zero-extend unsigned
    // values.
    return static_cast<intptr_t>(arg);
#endif
  }
```

This code is fine under x64, but if it is x86, the length of the pointer is 4 bytes, and the length of long long is 8 bytes, which is obviously not true. I want to know how to modify this code ?

How to make this code support 32-bit and 64-bit more reasonably?

Comment: You could return an `int64_t`. `static_assert(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(int64_t))` should be always true. You should mention what you want to do with the result or what the input represents.

Comment: Don't pass a `long long` to this function and it will work fine on both 32- and 64-bit.

Comment: @mch   Thank you for your answer! // Helper methods to convert arbitrary integer or pointer arguments to the needed generic argument type intptr_t. （Will this modification have any adverse effects?）

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot How to convert long long into pointer form in 32 bits?

Comment: first figure out why they want it to return intptr_t?

Comment: ok let me look at the call stack
@user253751

Comment: You should paste link to repo with this piece of code: https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/6.7.288.33/src/simulator-base.h#86

Comment: @pyj You cannot convert an eight byte quantity to a four byte quantity (without losing information). That is the point of the error. And as already said the solution is not to call that function with `long long`. In other words the problem is not in that function, it is behaving as designed. The problem is in the code calling that function.

Comment: @john Thanks, as you said, it was a test with incorrect parameters, the function itself is fine.